# mysqli - fetch_Array error call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am new to mysqli and started trying to learn basic things.  With respect to this i example (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) i was trying fetch_array. Here is my code.

```
$sqlGetChartData    =   "SELECT date, ratepersqft, location 
                          FROM ratepersqft
                         WHERE project_id = 1";
$runGetChartData    =   $mysqli->query($sqlGetChartData);

while($rowGetChartData = $runGetChartData->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
    $arrGetChartData[]  =   $rowGetChartData;

    print "<pre>";
    print_r($arrGetChartData);
    exit();
```

Here i am getting this error Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object  on line next to while condition line.  I tried googling it and did not get result for my problem.  Hope my question is clear.  Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This answer has been written very long time ago and become irrelevant.

Since then I learned the proper solution for this problem and wrote it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582). Please navigate there.

Comment: That was such a nice way of explaining this, +1.

Comment: Don't you think this answer could use some retouch? I don't agree with the solution proposed. Maybe we should close it as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582

Comment: As you know, closing as a dupe doesn't really change anything, but I'll try t do something.

Answer (score 8):

The query probably failed and `mysqli::query` returned FALSE. Therefore `$runGetChartData` is not a `mysqli_result` object, but a `boolean`, which is why you are getting your error.

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.